# Maya camera navigation while keeping blender keymap

Tags: camera

Im learning Blender. I want to keep the native shortcuts for learning purposes but I like Maya's alt centric camera navigation . is there a way to do this?  Thank you

Comment: Hey there and welcome. Please provide more details as to how you expect the camera to work, while we may be able to point out where to change things, most likely people answering here are not very familiar with how Maya does it. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Edit > Preferences > Keymap**

Search for "rotate" and set your custom shortcut :

[image]

Also, I don't remember if maya rotates the viewport based on selection pivot but to set this behaviour go to **Edit > Preferences > Navigation** and check the "**Orbit around selection**" :
[image]